# Как с помощью GULP конвертировать .tif или .webp в JPG или любой другой формат?

Tags: gulp, frontend, webpack, tif

Как с помощью GULP конвертировать **.tif** или **.webp** в JPG или любой другой формат изображений, например `*.PNG`, `*.BMB`, `*.JEPG` ?

Или как сжать **.tif** средствами GULP или WebPack? Что-то в роде этого [tiff2jpg](http://tiff2jpg.com/ru/).

Если нет возможности реализовать на GULP подскажите на чем можно оптимизировать процесс сжатия или конвертации.

Нужно это для того чтобы  сжать изображения и залить фотографии на сайт. Все бы хорошо, но у меня в GULP файлы с расширением .tif не сжимаются.

Использую:  **gulp-image-optimization** 
*Ошибка: `Skipping unsupported image .tif`*

Пробовал: gulp-imagemin, gulp-imag;